# Google image sitemap : maximum length

Tags: sitemap, images

I read that you could put 50k urls in a sitemap. Problem : in an image sitemap, you got the page url, and a url for each image provided.
Does the limit apply to the number of pages, of images, or the total ?

Thanks

Comment: I would _think_ it would be the "total". In an images sitemap you can have a max of 1000 image URLs per page URL. If the limit was only for "page URLs" then you could potentially have 50,000 page URLs, each with 1,000 image URLs, giving a total of 50,000,000 URLs. This would far exceed the filesize limit of 50MB many times over.